# Kazam did not ask to save my recording and now it is lost

Tags: video, kazam

I just finised recording with Kazam but it didn't ask me to save my video recording and now my whole video is nowhere to be seen. Is this common, was my video too long? All I did was press "finish recording" and now I can't find the video from the folder I use to save every video. Thank You!

Comment: Kazam makes it far too easy to lose your work. Use vokoscreen instead. They should really pull it from the ubuntu software store it's not nearly good enough.

Comment: I guess a generic file undelete application could work, if you haven't written any new data to that partition

Comment: I found this recovered the video for me: https://superuser.com/a/1657583/470575 but the recovered audio was messed up so had to redo the video regardless

Answer (score 4):

2 possibilities:

- If you have set in `File`> `preferences` > `screencast`, `automatic File saving` to `ON`, it will be saved in the folder that you've chosen.
  By default it's in `~/Videos` but maybe you've changed it.
- if not, at the end of the recording, `kazam` asks you `save for later` and then let you choose the destination folder.

Remark: There's a bug about the custom destination folder. Each time you relaunch `kazam`, the destination folder is reset to the default `~/Video` even if you've changed it before.

Comment: The fact that it doesn't save the custom folder can make you lose all your video, if there's not enough free space in that folder. For long videos, I would use any other tool that just writes to a specific file or folder, not one that saves to a temp folder and then moves it elsewhere.